# Coconut oil vs Olive oil: Spray dynamics

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, biochemistry, kinetics

Ps: If this would better fit Physics then please move it there or let me know. I put it here based on fact that viscosity and colloids were part of chemistry curriculum 10/15 yrs back in school.

Let's say we had to spray Edible oil.

How would spraying each differ?

How different are their Physical Properies when it comes to spraying and how would they affect the spray and compare with each other?

(You may point out Properies that matter in spraying that I may not be aware of, but these are few I can remember from school/ college such as viscosity, stickiness, cohesion, adhesion, density)

Also, I understand temperature would/ could play a role as well, so let's specify and put them at their ideal temperature for spraying.

Let's optimize this spraying experiment for both of them & compare.

I'd love to hear the science in play here.

Ps: I'm curious if any of the follow terms apply to these Virgin oils: homogenous, colloidal, plasma?

Comment: Your question is rather broad and unclear. It would help if you made it more specific. (For example, how does the coconut/olive oil from your title make it into the question?)

Comment: @R.M. - Its late night and I've got to crash, but it comes because water is easy to spray, but these Oils have higher viscosity & stickyness that will cause  differences in spraying them

Answer (score 1):

The fluid dynamics of spray calculations depend on many conditions including the nozzle used to create the spray.  The wikipedia article on [spray nozzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spray_nozzle) has a good discussion on how different liquid properties tend to affect spray. Spray information tends to be empirical, so it is not really science at play, it is engineering.

The [Institute of Liquid Atomization and Spray Systems](http://www.ilass.org/) is a professional society set up around the science and engineering of spraying.  *[Atomization and Sprays](http://www.begellhouse.com/journals/atomization-and-sprays.html)* is a periodical journal set up around this entire topic.  A internet search of 'textbook on spray and atomization' turns up many textbooks on the topic.

Plenty of manuscripts written by scientists exist providing detailed results of experiments comparing sprays.  An example would be an experiment done comparing the spray of waste cooking oils in an engine when it is used as fuel.

Summarizing a discussion of all of these experiments is too broad and out of the scope of SE.  If you are interesting in learning about sprays make sure you have some understanding of fluid dynamics.  Conduct a literature review relevant to the spray experiment you have in mind.